# Calling SQL scalar function from Linq Query

Tags: sql, linq, function, edmx, scalar

There are many similar threads here, but none of them can't solve my problem.

As far as I know, there are two methods for calling SQL scalar function from linq.

## 1. method:

**I've added my function to .edmx file using XML editor and my function is:**

```
<Function Name="prisustvoPostotci" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
  <CommandText>
    select dbo.prisustvoPostotci(@matica_ID,@godina)
  </CommandText>
  <Parameter Name="matica_ID" Type="int" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="godina" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

I went to **model browser** and double clicked on my function in **Function Imports** and **changed return collection type to Int32**. My function is returning integer.

**Now I can call my function from linq using:**

```
using (DB_Entities dm = new DB_Entities())
{
  dm.prisustvoPostotci(1, 2016).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

It returns valid integer value!

**But if I call my function from Linq Query like this:**

```
query = query.Where(x => x.date.Value.Year == max_year &&
                dm.prisustvoPostotci(x.ID, max_year).FirstOrDefault() >= 50);
```

**It throws this error:**

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]
>   prisustvoPostotci(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],
>   System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

## 2. method:

**I've added my function to .edmx file using XML editor and my function is:**

```
<Function Name="prisustvoPostotci" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
  <CommandText>
    select dbo.prisustvoPostotci(@matica_ID,@godina)
  </CommandText>
  <Parameter Name="matica_ID" Type="int" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="godina" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

I went to **model browser** and double clicked on my function in **Function Imports** and **changed return collection type to Int32**. My function is returning integer.

**Then I created a partial class and wrote this method:**

```
public static class EntityFunctions
{
    [EdmFunction("Model.Store", "prisustvoPostotci")] 
    public static int prisustvoPostotci(int matica_ID, int godina) 
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls not supported"); 
    } 

}
```

**"Model.Store" is the correct name of my Model Store read from my Schema Namespace inside .edmx file.**

**Now, if I call my function from linq using:**

```
EntityFunctions.prisustvoPostotci(119, 2016).ToString()
```

**It throws this error:**

> throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls not supported");

**Also, if I call my function from Linq Query like this:**

```
query = query.Where(x => x.date.Value.Year == max_year &&
                EntityFunctions.prisustvoPostotci(x.ID, max_year) >= 50);
```

**It throws this error:**

> The function or function import 'Model.Store.prisustvoPostotci' is not composable. A non-composable function or function import cannot be called in a query expression.

**I tried to edit my .edmx file and change a property IsComposable="true", but it gives me this error:**

> Functions declaring command text cannot be composed.

Can You help me solve this problem!?
Many thanks in advance !!

::cheers::

Josip

Comment: You should define a return type: https://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/first-impressions-of-database-first-development-with-entity-framework-5-in-visual-studio-2012/

Comment: If You meant to add ReturnType="int" or ReturnType="Int32" to my .edmx file, then it returns this error: "Functions that cannot be composed must not declare a return type." ??

Comment: You're trying to use a scalar function as a composable function (i.e. usable in a query, like in your `Where` clause). That's only supported for table-values functions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with table functions. Can table function be implemented instead scalar function to return an integer value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gerd Arnold I realize that scalar functions cannot be used inside query where statement.

Here is how I managed to filter my query by calling scalar function outside query:

```
var result = query.ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    // prisustvoPostotci(ID, year) is my scalar function
    if (dm.prisustvoPostotci(result[i].ID, max_year).FirstOrDefault() >= 50)
    {
        result.Remove(result[i]);
        i--;
    }
}
```

This way calling scalar function will work and we can remove matching records from the result!

Hope this will help someone.

:: cheers ::

Josip